# Error about example in book

Tags: compiler-errors, dev-c++

Im very starter in C++ and i want to learn because im studying Software Engineering, i bought a book i was trying to do that examples in dev c++ and i got a error that i couldnt found the solution on net. Here is the code and error below;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{

    char a;
    int i;
    i =-+;
    while (i=255) {i++;
    printf("%.3d. Alphabet: %c\n",i,i);
    a= getch();

    };
}
```

in book says output be like ;

1. Alphabet : A
2. Alphabet : B
   and so on..

problem is when i press compile it says;

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

can anybody tell me what is it?

Comment: Couple of copy paste errors: i=-+;  while(i=255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you are looking is as below:

```
char a;
int i;
i =0;
while (i!=255) {i++;
  printf("%.3d. Alphabet: %c\n",i,i);
};
a= getch();
```

First you must assign a default zero value to i
, Then you need loop to count from zero to 255 so instead of while(i=255) must use while(i!=255)
and pit getch out of loop too show all characters and then wait for your click to exit the application

Comment: Thanks!! thats the solution i was looking for 
i noted to myself; set i =0 then add +1 thanks for your help

Comment: If that was solution could you please select my answer as  the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

Exactly what the error says: the compiler expects a "full" expression where he found a `;`. Typically, compilers (gcc in your case) emit line numbers, too, and that would directly point you to where your problem is.

```
i =-+;
```

Simply neither makes sense, nor is valid C++; maybe you wanted to write

```
i =- 1;
```

or the like?

Also, make sure to use [a recent version of dev C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info), or another IDE (there's so many more popular ones out there).

Comment: Thanks for editing the article (i didnt know how to put those like this.) yea also i=-1 works 
and i downloaded newest version of dev C++

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what line the error is on, but I'm guessing it's on the `i =-+` line, because that's nonsensical:  `-+` is not a number that you can assign to a variable.

Also, `while (i=255)` will loop forever, setting `i` to 255 every time around.  (The `i++` afterward will mean that `i` will be 256 in your `printf` statement each time.)  You probably meant `while (i < 255)`.

Most likely, you've mistyped the code from your book.  If those errors are actually printed in the book, you should get a better book, one whose editor didn't let huge obvious mistakes slip through.

Comment: yea sorry about that it was in that line but i found the solution the i=-+ doesnt make any sense thanks for your advice it really helped me